# Drag and drop Blob object from Angular app Chrome Browser to windows

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, browser, drag-and-drop

I am using mat-table in my angular 7 using chrome as default browser.

I need to develop a feature: On clicking any part of each row in mat -table, it will download that document in blob object.We can drag the blob and drop to windows.

Blob object can be attached to any HTML element to make the element draggable.

Can we do this feature or do we have any 3rd party tool to do this.

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by *windows*. And why blob should be used to make something draggable

Comment: Thanks for @x00 checking my request. I am downloading file from POST request from httpClient.get<Blob> api in angular
 `const fileBlob = await this.httpClient.get<Blob>('backendserviceUrl',
{param:attachement:'true'}, 
withCredentials:'true',
responseType:'blob' as 'json')}`
windows  or for any other OS I meant to say desktop

Comment: Please let me know if you happen to know any other solution from where File in web browser angular app can be dragged and dropped to OS like the Gmail attachement does it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12610347/x00 @x00 any pointers